Create two separate mount points with different subfolders for the same /dev/sda1 device
I created three mount points for the /dev/sda1 device :
admin_pri@mypc:/opt$ findmnt | grep sda1
├─/opt/pacbio_data                       /dev/sda1                                        ext4            rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,stripe=16
├─/opt/pacbio_local                      /dev/sda1                                        ext4            rw,relatime,stripe=16
└─/opt/aviti_smbshare                    /dev/sda1                                        ext4            rw,relatime,stripe=16

The first one /opt/pacbio_data is used as a buffer to transfer data from another device to an external storage S3.
My issue concerns the two others mount points : the /opt/pacbio_local  is like the original one that works. I just created the second one /opt/aviti_smbshare with sudo mount /dev/sda1/ /opt/aviti_smbshare/ : it works but :

the owner/group names of /opt/aviti_smbshare take the owner/group names of the /opt/pacbio_local
the subfolders of /opt/pacbio_local are also created into /opt/aviti_smbshare

It also appears only one mount for sda1.
admin_pri@mypc:/opt$ lsblk -f | grep sda
    sda
    └─sda1      ext4           1f4bb512-5d9d-440f-8a84-54693fb5b71a /opt/aviti_smbshare

Is that normal? Because I would like to get two distincts mount points.
Best

You cannot mount the same partition on different PATH if you want to separate data. creating some specific directories under /opt/pacbio_data and mount them as loop device should help.

thanks for the advice! and my current architecture is fine enough ?

Probably as /opt/pacbio_datais temporary files, I would prefer to create directories under /opt/pacbio_local such as SMB & S3 for the other mounts

Consider using --rbind.  See Understanding Bind Mounts.  The approach you've taken will work better if you add these.

Thanks @admstg and eyoung100. I will go with subdirectories then.
